# Max(Date) query with another condition

Tags: sql-server-2008

my record:

```
SF_ID    CardID   Status  Received_Date    Meetup_Date

12    1   Yes     2015-01-12       2015-12-03    
13    1   No      2015-12-01       NULL
14    1   No      2015-12-01       NULL
15    2   No      2015-12-02       NULL
16    2   No      2015-12-02       NULL
17    3   No      2015-12-01       NULL
18    4   No      2015-12-06       NULL
19    5   Yes     2015-11-30       2015-12-01 
20    5   No      2015-11-30       NULL
22    5   No      2015-11-30       NULL
23    7   yes     2015-12-06       2015-12-07
```

Requirement #1:

all `cardID` where `Received_Date` is Minimum and `Status`
is `No` and `Top 01 SF_ID`. I've tried it in the following way without success:

```
SELECT CardSFID, 
       CardID, 
       CardSFShortDate 
FROM   CC_Shortfall AS [data] 
WHERE  ( CardSFShortDate = (SELECT TOP 1 PERCENT CardSFShortDate 
                            FROM   CC_Shortfall 
                            WHERE  CardID = [data].CardID) ) 
       AND CardSFYesNo = 'No'
```

Requirement #2:

all `cardID` Where `MeetUp_Date` is Maximum and `Status`
is `Yes` and there are not any `No Status` under `CardID`

i've tried to do it in the following way without succcess:

```
SELECT CardSFID, 
       CardID, 
       CardSfShortRcvDate 
FROM   CC_Shortfall AS [data] 
WHERE  ( CardSfShortRcvDate = (SELECT Max(CardSfShortRcvDate) 
                               FROM   CC_Shortfall 
                               WHERE  CardID = [data].CardID) ) 
       AND CardSFYesNo = 'Yes'
```

Comment: I tried to create an environment to test and come up with a solution but it seems that there are some discrepancies between the data and the query. CardSfShortRcvDate is nowhere to be found in the data that you presented... Please correct.

Comment: "all cardID where Received_Date is Minimum and Status is No and Top 01 SF_ID" is difficult to understand... Please put what you want to see as results